# Python TimeDelta Code works in Python IDE, but not when I run it through SPSS

Tags: python, spss

I'm trying to calculate which fiscal week a day falls into, and my code runs correctly in Spyder and PythonTutor, but when I try running it through SPSS's Python functionality, I get a different error.

Code in Spyder:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
VisitDate=date(2017,9,10)

def WhichWeek(DateOfVisit):
   StartDate=date(2017,9,1)
   EndDate=StartDate+timedelta(days=+6)
   Beginning=StartDate
   End=EndDate
   NumberWeeks=10
   for i in range(NumberWeeks):
      if(DateOfVisit>=Beginning and DateOfVisit<=End:
         print('It worked',i)
         return i
      else:
         print ('It failed', i, Beginning, End)
         Beginning=Beginning+timedelta(days=+7)
         End=End+timedelta(days=+7)

WhichWeek(VisitDate)
```

This runs, and returns the expected value.  (The print statements are there just to help troubleshoot it).

However, when I run it in SPSS using the Python Extension:

```
begin program.
def WhichWeek(DateOfVisit):
   from datetime import date, timedelta
   StartDate = date(2016,9,1)
   EndDate=StartDate+timedelta(days=+6)
   Beginning=StartDate
   End=EndDate
   NumberWeeks=10
   for i in range(NumberWeeks):
       if DateOfVisit>=Beginning and DateOfVisit<=End:
           print('It worked',i)
           return i
       else:
           print ('It failed', i, Beginning, End)
           Beginning=Beginning+timedelta(days=+7)
           End=End+timedelta(days=+7)

end Program.

SPSSINC TRANS RESULT=Week_Test /FORMULA WhichWeek(VisitDate).
EXECUTE.
FREQUENCIES VARIABLES=Week_Test
  /FORMAT=DFREQ
  /ORDER=ANALYSIS.
```

It now gives me the error "The Forumla References an undefined variable or could not be evaluated: can't compare datetime.date to float

VisitDate is a defined variable in my SPSS dataset, and since I don't get this error in Spyder, I'm at a loss for where to continue troubleshooting.

Edit: I changed my Spyder version from VisitDate1 to VisitDate to limit confusion.  I should also say that in Spyder I'm running it against a static date to test if it identifies the week correctly (2017-09-10) and not an actual dataset.  In SPSS, I'm running it against a dataset.

Comment: In the Python code, you are calling the function for variable `VisitDate1` . In the SPSS syntax, it is just `VisitDate`. Is it the same variable ? Do both have the same format ? The error says you are referencing a non-existing variable, so my guess is you got the wrong variable in the SPSS syntax ;)

Comment: VisitDate is the variable in SPSS.  I'm aware they are different variables between Spyder and SPSS, but that is more related to other unrelated code in Spyder.

Regarding Format, I'm I've tried it with a few different Date formats in SPSS and it hasn't worked, so I don't know if it is a format issue in SPSS.

Comment: Try printing the type of each variable. See which one is float. Then convert both to the same type. This sounds a bit non-pythonian, but if that is the error you are getting...